# Switching from branch-a to branch-b changes file permissions. But reverting *back* to branch-a does *not* revert the file permissions. Why is that?

Tags: git, permissions

Currently, in my local repo, I have checked out a branch named `mybranch`, and all my files have permissions of 644 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLe2m.jpg)).  There are no edits in the working directory, and nothing in the staging area.  If I checkout the `master` branch, the permissions for two files change to 664 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks6tC.jpg)).  If I immediately checkout `mybranch` again, the permissions of those files do *not* change back to 644--they remain at 664.  I have three related questions:

1. Why don't the permissions change *back* to 644 when I checkout `mybranch`?  Shouldn't they?
2. When I checkout the `master` branch, why do those changes to permissions occur at all?  I thought Git tracked only the user's execute permission.
3. How do I properly ensure that the permissions on all files remain at 644, regardless of branch?

   ---

A few items of possible note:

- I created this repo--and the master branch--while logged in as a particular Linux user:  `user-a`.  At that time, I don't recall the permissions on the two files in-question.  But there is a decent chance they could have been 664.
- After creating the repo, I began using a different Linux user:  `user-b`.  I migrated the entire repo to a different directory on the computer, into an area accessible only by `user-b`.  All my current work is being done while logged in as `user-b`.
- I believe I created `mybranch` after I began using `user-b`, but I can't remember for sure.
- In a separate forum post, someone mentioned that all permissions are saved at the repo level, in the file `.git/index`.  So reverting back to the `master` branch always applies the permissions saved in that file.   That person didn't know how to view the permissions set in that file, and said I might be able to use [`git-update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) to change the permissions in that file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git doesn't store group permissions at all.<sup>1</sup>  Files are either `mode 100644`, which means they're `rw-`, or they are `mode 100755`, which means they're `rwx`.

The mode strings `100644` and `100755` respectively would imply `rw-r--r--` and `rwxr-xr-x` respectively when used as Unix modes.  They originally *were* Unix (or Linux) modes—but they aren't any more, not for a very long time, back before hardly anyone but Linus was using Git.

Instead, when Git creates a file on its own, it uses a `mode` argument of either `0666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) or `0777` (`rwxrwxrwx`).  *Your computer operating system* then chips away at some of these mode bits, based on *your personal umask setting*.  This personal setting is per-process and normally is something you manipulate in your shell.

The *default* chip-away bits are typically `----w--w-`, i.e., `rwxrwxrwx` becomes `rwxr-xr-x`.  This is achieved with a `umask` setting of `022`.

To tell your shell to create new processes with the chip-away bits set to `-------w-` instead, use `umask 002`.  (You can leave out the leading zeros if you like; I like to keep them for clarity.)

The change to `664` seems odd, but perhaps you're doing that in a shell with the umask set to `002`, and doing the checkouts that leave you with `644` in a shell with the umask set to the default `022`.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the case of a shared *bare* repository, there are certain group-permissions properties that apply.  But that's not what is going on here.

Comment: You mention, "The change to 664 seems odd, but perhaps you're doing that in a shell with the umask set to 002, and doing the checkouts that leave you with 644 in a shell with the umask set to the default 022."  All I'm doing to incur these changes is checking out a different Git branch.  Could that possibly result in a change to the shell, as you've described?

Comment: That doesn't seem likely, but if you have two different shell windows open, perhaps the two different shell windows have different umask settings. To see your current setting, run the shell's built-in `umask` command, which prints the current value rather than setting a new one.

Comment: Right now, the permissions on the files is set to 664, and running `umask` returns `0002`. 
 That is the case regardless of whether I'm in the `master` branch, or `mybranch`. So at this point, how would you suggest I fix this?  i.e. how can I ensure the permissions on these files is set to 644, and stays at 644 regardless of branch?  Can I simply try switching to `master`, then setting the permissions to 644? I admittedly don't think I've even tried that yet.

Comment: The fact that `umask` returns `0002` now means that any *new* file Git—or almost any other program, really—creates now will have mode `664` (non-executable) or `775` (executable). You can use `chmod` any time you want on any such file; it's only *new* files that will be set to this mode. When you use `git checkout` or `git switch` to move from one commit to another, Git will *remove and re-create* any files that are different in the two commits, so their permissions will obey your current umask.

Comment: If you want future-created files to have mode `664`, set your umask to `022` now, and find out what is setting it to `002` and change that setting.

Comment: Thanks for that. You wrote, "if you want future-created files to have mode 664, set your umask to 022 now..." Did you mean to type 'mode 644?' I believe so, but just want to be sure.

Comment: Oops, yes, typo, I did mean `mode 644` above.

Comment: OK thanks.  Give me a few days to look into this and test some things. I'll report back here.

Comment: OK I spoke with my web host.  He said my default umask was 022, but due to recent changes on their end, my user profile (.bash_profile) had umask set to 002, which was superseding the 022.  He had me manually edit .bash_profile for my user, to umas=022.  When I did so, the permissions on the files immediately reverted back to 644.  Plus, the permissions stayed that way, regardless of Git branch.  So everything you said was true, and worked--thank you!  I'll mark yours as the answer.